# Convert Python Dictionary to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting a python list/dictionary to a pandas dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

points = [
    {'coords': (100.5, 100), 'class': 1},
    {'coords': (300, 300), 'class':2},
    {'coords': (50, 200), 'class':4},
    {'coords': (550, 400), 'class':10},
    {'coords': (550, 300), 'class':1}
    ]

 # pandas data frame
 data = np.array([['x', 'y', 'class']])
 for point in points:
    row = [point['coords'][0], point['coords'][1], point['class']] 
    data = np.vstack((data, row))

 df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])
 df.columns = data[0:1].tolist()
```

This gives following df:

> ```
>        x      y class
> 0  100.5  100.0   1.0
> 1    300    300     2
> 2     50    200     4
> 3    550    400    10
> 4    550    300     1
> ```

However, if I now try to do a calculation like:

```
df['mult'] = df['x'] * df['y']
```

I get an error with:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: That's strange, selecting column from `df` return object of type `DataFrame`, could anyone explain why is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why this (all columns have `object` dtype) is happening?

after this line:

```
In [100]: data = np.array([['x', 'y', 'class']])
```

array `data` will have `object` (string) dtype:

```
In [101]: data.dtype
Out[101]: dtype('<U5')
```

also after concatenating numeric values:

```
In [102]: data = np.vstack((data, (100.5, 100, 1)))

In [103]: data
Out[103]:
array([['x', 'y', 'class'],
       ['100.5', '100.0', '1.0']], dtype='<U32')

In [104]: data.dtype
Out[104]: dtype('<U32')
```

you could collect only numeric values in `data` and construnct DF as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y', 'class'])
```

---

But I'd try a slightly different approach:

```
In [80]: df = pd.DataFrame(points)

In [81]: df[['x','y']] = df.pop('coords').apply(pd.Series)

In [82]: df
Out[82]:
   class      x      y
0      1  100.5  100.0
1      2  300.0  300.0
2      4   50.0  200.0
3     10  550.0  400.0
4      1  550.0  300.0

In [83]: df['mult'] = df['x'] * df['y']

In [84]: df
Out[84]:
   class      x      y      mult
0      1  100.5  100.0   10050.0
1      2  300.0  300.0   90000.0
2      4   50.0  200.0   10000.0
3     10  550.0  400.0  220000.0
4      1  550.0  300.0  165000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this converting dtype of dataframe to float and using np.multiply function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

points = [
    {'coords': (100.5, 100), 'class': 1},
    {'coords': (300, 300), 'class':2},
    {'coords': (50, 200), 'class':4},
    {'coords': (550, 400), 'class':10},
    {'coords': (550, 300), 'class':1}
    ]

# pandas data frame
data = np.array([['x', 'y', 'class']])
for point in points:
    row = [point['coords'][0], point['coords'][1], point['class']] 
    data = np.vstack((data, row))


df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],dtype=float)
df.columns = data[0:1].tolist()
df['mult'] = np.multiply(df['x'],df['y'])
df['mult']
    mult
0   10050.0
1   90000.0
2   10000.0
3   220000.0
4   165000.0
```